# What's the official stance on physics-based questions that show no research effort?

Tags: discussion

Example: [How big could a space-ship get while still being plausible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/179623/how-big-could-a-space-ship-get-while-still-being-plausible)

It's asking about what sort of energy expenditure would be necessary to move a moon-sized starship capable of effective-faster-than-light travel.

Anyone who has done even the most basic research into physics knows that the answer is a lot of energy. No seriously, a LOT. As in, an almost unimaginable amount. Probably more in a second than our entire planet currently generates every year.

As such, there can't really be a good answer to such a question, because all answers are effectively going to boil down to "a lot of energy". Yes, you can take a guess then add some back-of-the-envelope physics calculations demonstrating how much your guess comes out to and relate it to something in the present, but at the end of the day you're still guessing, and honestly that's not achieving anything more than pointing the asker to one of many websites that has already gone through the same exercise.

In short, I don't think such questions add any value to this site. Am I correct?

If so, how should I treat such questions? I've been downvoting them, but should they rather be closed and pointed to a canonical duplicate instead?

(I also have an issue with the fact that said question has so many upvotes, but that's another conversation entirely.)

Comment: "*Acceleration for this ship doesn't really need to be all that fast, although it does need to be able to travel between solar systems in (at most) a month or so.*" is where the [reality-check] tag is truly needed.  The rest is noise.